# Positioning callouts in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm creating a Magento site using a custom 3-column template. I've added Best Selling Products in the right_col.phtml so I'm assuming that it would appear on my right sidebar. However, it's appearing on both the left and right columns of my layout. How come it's appearing on both sides of the template? The right_col block is literally called on both sides, I'm not sure why.

Comment: right_col.phtml is not a standard Magento template. You'll need to include code for it as well as any related layout XML.

Comment: actually, I guess this was a result of panicking. I'm working with 3 other people and one of them apparently added the file on the left side of the layout so it kept appearing there. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: It's a question worth answering. Another question would be, why is there a need for a column template? Magento layouts are pretty flexible there.